# Fedora 37/Wayland - Touchpad works but most gestures don't

Tags: fedora, drivers, touchpad, wayland, mouse-gestures

I've used Linux daily for over a decade but have always run it in a VM or on a server due to the user experience typically not being quite on par with Windows/OSX (without significant fiddling).

I have a spare laptop now so I'm giving Fedora 37 a test drive on a Dell Latitude 5530 and I've noticed that while the touchpad does work, two finger touch for right click does not, four finger swipe doesn't, and a single tap will not left click. The only gesture that does seem to work is two finger scrolling.

- GNOME Version: 43.0
- Windowing System: Wayland

Anyone bumped into this before and been able to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Hardly a real answer, but I just deleted Fedora and put Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on, which is officially supported by Dell, and gestures all work correctly.

This may help inform other's decision making on OS selection.

Edit: in true Linux fashion I allowed Ubuntu to update itself once and the very first update crashed promptly bricking the computer.

Well, I tried Linux. I tried .

[image]